# WebLogic 10.3 JPA 1.0 Missing descriptor for class

Tags: stored-procedures, jpa, weblogic-10.x

I'm using WebLogic 10.3 with JPA 1.0.

The entity class is:

```
@Entity
public class ZoneAgency implements Serializable {

   public ZoneAgency() {
      super();
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name = "zoneid", nullable = false)
   private Integer zoneId;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "agencyid", nullable = false)
   private Integer agencyId;
}
```

It is also added in persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="smthModel">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/smthDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>smth.model.entities.ZoneAgency</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="jdbc/smthDS"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I use this class in the following invocation:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("call get_zone_agency_by_channel_type_rr(?,?)", ZoneAgency.class);
```

where get_zone_agency_by_channel_type_rr is a stored procedure that returns the result of this select:

```
select t_zone_id as zoneid, t_agency_id as agencyid;
```

This entity class is wrapped inside a jar file that is used as a dependency in a web application (war file). This war is wrapped inside an ear file and deployed on WebLogic.

The problem is that 
when I install/update the deployment, the entityManager.createNativeQuery invocation works fine;
when I stop the Web application and then restart it, I get the following error:

```
Exception Description: Missing descriptor for [class smth.model.entities.ZoneAgency].
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=ZoneAgency sql="call get_zone_agency_by_channel_type_rr(?,?)")
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a class loader issue.  My guess is that the old persistence unit with the old classes are still deployed in the server.

When you use a container managed (injected/jta) persistence unit the server take care of undeploying it.

When you use an application managed persistence unit (Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()), then you must ensure you close it before redeploying a live server.  Otherwise it will remain deployed.

Comment: We're using an application managed persistence unit `   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "OpenXModel")
   protected EntityManager entityManager;`

Comment: You saved my day! (after hours reading half-internet and possible documentations and rechecking everything many times). I was deploying in a shared WL12c and didn't restarted since yestarday, where my persistence.xml was wrongly constructed and not properly closed because debuging breakpoints and testing. Thank you very much men!